# firestore post restriction

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I managed to use firestore in the app. Users can post a blog which will be updated in real time to all the users. I want to restrict users to post only one blog from their account. How can I make this possible? How can I restrict users from posting multiple posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Firestore Rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents { 
        match /blogs/{blogId} { 
            allow create: 
                if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userAuthId &&
                request.resource.data.authorNumOfBlogs == 0

            allow update, delete: 
                if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userAuthId
        }
     }
 }
```

This will only allow the user to create a blog if the request matches the current users id and if that user only has one blog post.

Be sure to make a field `authorNumOfBlogs` in your `/blogs` collection and increment/decrement it accordingly when the user creates/deletes a blog post. Also, add a `userAuthId` field in your `/users` collection if you are not already keeping track of the user's uid in firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading the post You can query the collection to see if already exists a post from that user.
If exists, You don't upload the post.
For this You need to save the uid of the user that create the document inside every post.